# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I am a beginner in jenkins and i need some help. I have the follow code

but when i build my job the result is an error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class

i need to return the result of my job to a pipeline. How can i do this?
thanks in advance

```
import hudson.model.*
def buildNumber = build.properties.environment.BUILD_NUMBER
println buildNumber
File file = new File("./SRC");
 if(file.exists()){
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        return
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the currentBuild property to get more information about the build:

```
def buildNumber = currentBuild.number
println buildNumber
```